# Tag synonym request [sneak] → [stealth]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I'd like to request a tag synonym for [sneak] into [stealth].

Sneaking in the sense of movement would fit well in stealth.

Comment: I couldn't find a "sneak" tag, but I merged the 3 "Sneaking" questions that I think you meant to refer to.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw [sneak] in use.

Answer (score 1):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)